# How to change dconf directory?

Tags: java, linux, singularity-container

I have created a singularity container that's purpose to run a java program. Everything seems to work, expect that I get the following warning:

```
(java:54036): dconf-CRITICAL **: 23:37:10.142: unable to create directory '/run/user/175387/dconf': Read-only file system.  dconf will not work properly.
```

From my search, I've learned that `dconf` is simply a system that stores configuration settings in some binary file. The singularity container is a read-only filesystem, so it is not surprising to me that issues such as this would come up.

When I invoke the singularity container, I can bind directories from the host OS. These bound directories may be writable. Therefore, my best guess is that all I need to do is change the dconf file to be located inside one of these bound, writable directories. So, my question is simply how this can be done.

The top-level `dconf` help output is:

```
Commands:
  help              Show this information
  read              Read the value of a key
  list              List the contents of a dir
  write             Change the value of a key
  reset             Reset the value of a key or dir
  compile           Compile a binary database from keyfiles
  update            Update the system databases
  watch             Watch a path for changes
  dump              Dump an entire subpath to stdout
  load              Populate a subpath from stdin
```

None of these seem to relate to changing the location of the dconf file.

One workaround might be to build a writable singularity container. But I'd prefer a different solution to keep the singularity container read-only.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, and the one I use for GUI programs run from singularity containers, is to mount the user's run directly to the container with `-B /run/user/$UID`.

If you are concerned about undesired dconf settings persisting for the user, I would suggest the `--writable-tmpfs` flag which creates a tmpfs overlay that can be used to modify the container image until the process completes.